# how to check if a variable is equal to a certain word

Tags: c

script is supposed to take input from the user and display that input when info is entered. it is storing the information, but after regardless of input it does not display the information. I think it has something to do with the if statement not being setup correctly and the == "info" not being correct but can't figure out how to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name;
    int age;

    printf("your name\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("your age\n");
    scanf("%s", &age);

    char input;
    scanf("%s", &input);
    if(&input == "info")
    {
        printf("%s\n", &name);
        printf("%s\n", &age);
    }

}
```

Comment: `name` has room for _one_ `char` so `scanf("%s", &name);` is doomed. `scanf("%s", &age);` tries to read a word into an `int`. You can't just make things up. You'll have to read the documentation for `scanf`.

Comment: `strcmp` is used in c to compare two "strings"

Comment: @TedLyngmo if i print name and age after getting input from the user it displays the information fine i'm not sure what you mean by being doomed can you elaborate? the only part of the script that is having a problem is when i try to check if the user has input the word info

Comment: What book are you using to learn C?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI i'm not using a book i've just read the basic documentation and am trying to understand it. i see now that char is only storing 1 character and i need to have an array to store the string

Comment: @user23299833 _" i'm not sure what you mean..."_ - Ok, I put it into an actual answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes thank you i am trying to decipher and learn from the code now but it's alot to absorb and very different from the basic stuff i've been messing around with

Comment: "i'm not using a book" That's your problem right here.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI yeah i'm interested in learning how C works and the logic behind it, is there a book you would recommend?

Comment: @user23299833 If you have a place (online or in a book) where you can look up the individual commands, deciphering my program should be fairly straight forward. Take one command at a time and try to understand it well. The `scanf` family is a bit special. It takes a long time to understand well :-) You could use https://en.cppreference.com/w/c to lookup the commands for example.

Comment: Modern C by Jens Gustedt (there is a free version but buy a printed edition if you can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `char` can only store `1` character.
- strings in C language are arrays of `char` elements with `0` at the end (it is called null terminating character)
- you cant use `==` in C to compare strings. You need to use functions from `string.h` - in this case `strcmp`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[50];
    int age[50];

    printf("your name\n");
    scanf("%49s", name);

    printf("your age\n");
    scanf("%49s", age);

    char input[20];
    scanf("%19s", input);
    if(strcmp(input, "info") == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", name);
        printf("%s\n", age);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for the response and for keeping it as basic as possible for me. very helpful answer

Comment: just one question, what does the == 0 mean in the if statement? i know it's important and won't work without it but don't understand why

Comment: @user23299833 because this function returns `0` when both strings are the same

Comment: nevermind figured out strcmp returns 0 which triggers the if statement

Answer (score 4):

The program has *undefined behavior* and could do just about anything.

- `name` is but *one* `char` and can only fit one letter. It needs to fit at least two letters to be able to have the required null terminator `\0` (which is what tells `printf` etc where the string ends). Since it doesn't, `scanf` will write out of bounds.
- You use the wrong conversion specifiers for both `scanf` and `printf`. `%s` is for words/strings, not `int`. `%d` is the correct conversion specifier for `int`.
- `if(&input == "info")` compares two *addresses* not two strings. You should use `strcmp` to compare strings.
- `scanf`s `%s` reads a word and if the name contains more than one word, you're out of luck. I suggest using `fgets` to read strings instead of a word.

Slightly modified to not use `scanf` directly since it complicates things when mixing `scanf` and `fgets`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char name[256]; // room for 255 char + \0
    int age;
    char input[32];

    puts("your name");
    if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin) == NULL) return 1;
    name[strcspn(name, "\n\r")] = '\0'; // chop off at \n or \r

    puts("your age");
    char tmp[16];
    if (fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin) == NULL) return 1;

    // now use sscanf on the tmp buffer and check that it succeeds:
    if (sscanf(tmp, "%d", &age) != 1) return 1;

    if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL) return 1;
    input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = '\0';

    // compare the content of input with the string "input",
    // 0 means that they are equal:
    if (strcmp(input, "input") == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", name);
        printf("%d\n", age);
    }
}
```